# How can I get Joomla component parameter values?

Tags: joomla

===

UPDATE:

I think now I am literally just trying to get a database value into my component php files, but again, there seems to be very little documentation that can give an example of a function that will return this info like there is in Wordpress.

So I have a table called membersarea_countries that will have records of differnt countries I want to store values for.

I've read about JTable and other things, but how can I simply just bring back the records from this table?

```
$row = JTable::getInstance('membersarea_countries', 'Table', array());
```

But this returns a boolean of 0.

I'd really appreciate some help if anyone can.

===

I've been following what several online guides explain, which are all pretty much the same thing, but I never seem to return the values that I'm expecting.

In Components > Members Area (my component), I have a table set up to allow me to enter a record for each country, and then store a uniqueRef, signature, and URL within that record. (for GeoIP purposes).

I've created the first record, however when I try to use the following code, which the tutorials suggest, I don't see any of my fields within this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getParams();
$uniqueRef = $params->get('uniquereference');
$signature = $params->get('signature');
```

This is all I see in NetBeans:
[image]

There's nothing about $app, and no sign of the fields I've got in the Joomla backend.

I don't understand what's happening, or exactly what I should be doing here. Wordpress uses a simple get_option function. Can anyone try and help me?

Comment: Please go through this - https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Comment: Have done, but my question has now changed to relate to tables. I realise it wasn't the parameters I was referring to at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the link to the detailed document about JTable -

https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class

Firstly you need to create JTable instance using below code and also change table file name to membersareacountries.php

```
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_membersarea/tables');
$row = JTable::getInstance('Membersareacountries', 'Table', array());
```

JTable Class in this file `/administrator/components/com_membersarea/tables/membersareacountries.php`-

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die();

class TableMembersareacountries extends JTable
{
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        parent::__construct( '#__membersarea_countrie', 'id', $db );
    }
}
```

Then you can use load method to get any records. This accepts primary key value of that table -

```
$id = 1;//change id as per your record
$row->load($id);

//read data
echo $row->id;
echo $row->title;
```

Comment: If I use the first section of code, replace com_recipes with com_membersarea, and then do a var_dump on $row, this returns as false

Comment: @Lee : you should also try to remove the underscore from the class name. Change filename and class name without underscore and let me know the response.

Comment: Sorry, can you help identify the class name and filename? Are you referring to your code?

Comment: Removed _countries from the second line, and still returning false

Comment: I have updated my answer. Your table class name should be - Membersareacountries. In case of issue you should also update your question about file name of the table and code inside it.

Comment: My apologies, still false I'm afraid. But the name of the table in the DB is #_membersarea_countries. I notice in the doc you linked, it states just 'recipes', but even with just 'membersarea' it still returns false.

Comment: Okay, so in the administrator PHP File the line shows `class MembersareaTablecountry extends JTable` so from what I understand I use `$row = JTable::getInstance('tablecountry', 'Membersarea', array());`, however this is still false

Comment: By the way, the file is called country.php, should 'country' be the first parameter for getInstance?

Comment: Got a result by using `$row = JTable::getInstance('country', 'Membersareatable', array());`

Comment: But rather than specifying an ID, because I'll be storing table rows for GeoIP details, at this point, can I do a search for a particular column value in the entire table, and then proceed to get that row?